# Finding the values of p and q in a quadratic equality

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

Let's say we have the quadratic equality $$6 - 4x -x^2 = q -(x+p)^2$$
How do I find the values of p and q if they are real integers?

Comment: cf. [Completing the square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completing_the_square)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expand the square on the right hand side to get
$$6-4x-x^2=q-p^2-2px-x^2.$$
This shows that $-4=-2p$ and $6=q-p^2$, so $p=2$ and $q=10$.